# Cannot read property '$on' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Trying to use events in AngularJS but getting the error stated in the title.

[Followed this example](http://coding-issues.blogspot.se/2013/11/call-controller-from-another-controller-angularjs.html) which seems pretty straight forward so not really sure about what might be causing the error.

My code:

```
.controller('FooterCtrl', [function($scope) {

    var showTime = false;

     $scope.$on('flip', function (event, args) {
        showTime = !showTime;
    });

}]);

.controller('View3Ctrl', [function($scope) { 

        $scope.$emit('flip', args);

}]);
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error and what it means? Why is $scope undefined?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJs $scope undefined when controllers are inside a module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284769/angularjs-scope-undefined-when-controllers-are-inside-a-module)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.controller('FooterCtrl', ["$scope",function($scope) {

    var showTime = false;

     $scope.$on('flip', function (event, args) {
        showTime = !showTime;
    });

}]);

.controller('View3Ctrl', ["$scope",function($scope) { 

    $scope.$emit('flip', args);

}]);
```

try this one